# Refreshing div with jquery, but undo last change

Tags: jquery

I have a table that colors the cell of the current "winner" based on 2 teams scores. It works great, but now I am trying to automate the process by refreshing the information within a div.

What it's doing is refreshing, but keeping the old highlighted cell as well. I want it to remove the highlight from the old cell, as well as highlight the new cell.

Here is what I am using now to highlight based on score:

```
function highlight(<?php echo $NFC_team; ?>, <?php echo $AFC_team; ?>) {
var col, row;
default 
col = $('#countit td').filter(function() { //return column of NFC Team
return $(this).html() === <?php echo $NFC_team; ?>.replace(' - ', '<br>');
}).index(); 

row = $('#countit tr').filter(function() { //return row of AFC Team
return $(this).html().indexOf(<?php echo $AFC_team; ?>.replace(' - ', '<br>')) > -1;
}).index();

$('tr').eq(row + 1).find('td').eq(col).css('background-color', '#ffff00');
} 

highlight('<?php echo $NFC_team; ?> - <?php echo $NFC_Score; ?>', '<?php echo $AFC_team; ?> - <?php echo $AFC_Score; ?>');
```

And here is what I use to refresh the div (that contains the above code as well):

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#refresh').load('table.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000); // refresh every 5 seconds
```

Seems simple but I have clue.

Comment: Before adding the highlight color to the winners, remove the highlighting from all the cells.

Comment: ^^ following the above comment it will  be easier to accomplish by toggling classes instead of setting inline css. Classes are easy to search for and all you need is css rule to make the style changes

Comment: I tried this but it's not working `$('tr').removeAttr('background-color', '#ffff00');`

Comment: have to remove whole `style` attribute....`'background-color'` is only part of the string in that attribute value

Comment: Like this?  `$(td).removeAttr('style');`

Comment: yes that would do it...still cleaner with class  ... `$('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted')`

Comment: I just want it to work, not concerned with cleanliness. When I use `$(td).removeAttr('style');` or `$(tr).removeAttr('style');`, the highlighting function stops working altogether.

Comment: You were right with the classes. Works much better. Add that as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks